# Google chart values on X axis not showing properly

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have two charts, they are being created by javascript the same exact way, one of them shows the values on x axis properly, the other doesn't.

So this is the traffic chart
[image]

As you can see the dates are shown properly under x axis, here is the code that generates this chart

```
function drawTrafficChart(processedData, humanReadableName, params) {
    dataArray = [];
    dataArrayRow = ['Date', 'Impressions', 'Detail Page Views'];
    dataArray.push(dataArrayRow);
    for (i in processedData) {
        dateString = processedData[i].date;
        dateString = formatDateStringAccordingToAggregationType(dateString, params);
        dataArrayRow = [dateString, processedData[i].event1, processedData[i].event2];
        dataArray.push(dataArrayRow);
    }

    var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
    var chartOptions = {
        title: 'Traffic Chart',
        hAxis: {title: humanReadableName},
        vAxis: {minValuex: 0},
        pointSize: 5,
        width: 670,
        height: 300
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('traffic_chart'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, chartOptions);
}
```

And this is the click chart
[image]

Here is the code that generates click chart

```
function drawClickChart(processedData, humanReadableName, params) {
    dataArray = [];
    dataArrayRow = ['Date', 'Website Clicks', 'Image Clicks', 'Video Clicks'];
    dataArray.push(dataArrayRow);
    for (i in processedData) {
        dateString = processedData[i].date;
        dateString = formatDateStringAccordingToAggregationType(dateString, params);
        dataArrayRow = [dateString, processedData[i].event3, processedData[i].event4, processedData[i].event5];
        dataArray.push(dataArrayRow);
    }

    var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
    var chartOptions = {
        title: 'Click Chart',
        hAxis: {title: humanReadableName},
        vAxis: {minValuex: 0},
        pointSize: 5,
        width: 670,
        height: 300
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('click_chart'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, chartOptions);
}
```

As you can see the dates on x axis are messed up, is there something I could do to fix this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you fiddled with the [hAxis Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options) like `hAxis.slantedText`, `hAxis.slantedTextAngle`, `hAxis.maxAlternation`, and `hAxis.maxTextLines`? If you fiddle around with those options, do any of them fix the problem slightly or totally? The issue may be that for some reason the google internal defaults aren't proper for your chart, and setting them manually may well solve the issue.

Comment: @Yasser1984 You can use `hAxis: {showTextEvery: 4}`. This will show off every 4th label on the x axis.